# Count Number of Instances of string using FORMULATEXT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have data that extends from **column A1 to F1**. All the cells contain `VLOOKUP` formulas looking up data from an external Excel file.

I want to be able to insert a formula in `column G1` to count the number of times a certain filename is used in columns A1 to F1.

I know that if the data in cells A1 to F1 were NOT formulas I could use something like the below in G1 if I was searching for the string "filename.xlsx" using wildcards:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:F1, "*filename.xlsx*")
```

However, as A1 to F1 contain formulas, I assume I would need to use FORMULATEXT, in order to look within the VLOOKUPs. I have tried the below, but it doesn't work:

```
=COUNTIF(FORMULATEXT(A1:F1),"*filename.xlsx*")
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this? it would also be good if the criteria within the COUNTIF was a cell reference. However, that isn't essential.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your `VLOOKUP` formula(s) that are used in your sheet?

Comment: The VLOOKUP in A1 is: =VLOOKUP(K2,'C:\ResultsDashboard\[Week2.xlsx]Dates'!$B:$D,2,). So I would like the formula in G1 to count the number of times Week2.xlsx occurred in A1 to F1.

Comment: I'm confused as to why a formula is needed for this. Although the formulas return a dynamic result, the `FORMULATEXT` will always return the same result. Couldn't you just count how many of your formulas in `A1` to `F1` use that file? Considering this is only 6 cells, it should not be difficult to do by hand, and I don't know why this result you are looking for would ever change. Why not just hardcode it?

Comment: Although only six columns are currently used, the dashboard I am producing is likely to grow considerably over the coming weeks. Possibly to over 40 columns, with many rows. Each row will look up to a different file. Therefore, counting by hand would be time consuming. There will also different versions of this dashboard as the weeks progress, and the filename that is being looked up to will change over time. For example, Week2.xlsx for now, but next week will be Week3.xlsx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this array formula

`=COUNT(SEARCH("filename.xlsx",FORMULATEXT(A1:F1)))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

or a non array version.....

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("filename.xlsx",FORMULATEXT(A1:F1)))+0)`

Comment: Thanks Barry Houdini, that works perfectly. Also thanks to ImaginaryHuman07289 and Vishva Dave for your help.